How to create a GAM with interation term for a soap film smoother
I am interested in creating a GAM that contains a soap film smoother that can also vary in time. Below is an example using synthetic data.
I start by creating data with two spatial signals, which are additive - one that is static in time and one that varies:
library(mgcv)
library(akima)

## create data -------------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(1)

# outer boundary
xbnd <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
ybnd <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)

# sample number
nsp <- 100 # number of spatial samples per year
nt <- 20 # number of years
n <- nsp * nt # total number of samples

# create data
dat <- expand.grid(samp = seq(nsp), time = seq(nt))
x <- runif(n)
y = runif(n)
dat$x <- x
dat$y <- y

# long-term spatial pattern
sp1 <- x^0.5+y^2
F1 <- interp(x = x, y = y, z = sp1)
image(F1)
contour(F1, add = T)
dat$sp1 <- sp1
  
# temporally-oscillating pattern
sp2 <- 1 - (((x-0.2)^2+(y-0.2)^2)^0.2)
F2 <- interp(x = x, y = y, z = sp2)
image(F2)
contour(F2, add = TRUE)

tp2 <- sin(seq(0, 5*pi, len = nt)) + 1.1
plot(seq(nt), tp2, t="l")

dat$sp2 <- tp2[dat$time] * sp2
dat$z <- dat$sp1 + dat$sp2 * rlnorm(nrow(dat), sdlog = 0.1) # add some noise

# examine a single year
with(subset(dat, time == 10), expr = {
  image(interp(x, y, z))
  points(x, y, pch = 20)
})

op <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
  image(F1)
  contour(F1, add = TRUE)
  mtext("static spatial pattern (sp1)")
  image(F2)
  contour(F2, add = TRUE)
  mtext("time-varying spatial pattern (sp2)")
  plot(1, t = "n", axes = F, xlab = "", ylab = "")
  plot(seq(nt), tp2, t="l", xlab = "time", ylab = "")
  mtext("time-varying signal (tp2)")
  mtext("X", line = 3, cex = 3)
par(op)


I then create a hole in the data and set up the appropriate boundary and knots:
## create knots and boundary -----------------------------------------------

# without hole
knots <- expand.grid(x = seq(0.1,0.9, length=5), 
                     y = seq(0.1,0.9, length=5))
bnd <- list(list(x = xbnd, y = ybnd))

# with hole
bnd2 <- list(
  list(x = xbnd, y = ybnd), 
  list(x = c(0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4), y = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4))
)
plot(dat$x, dat$y)
lapply(bnd2, lines)

hit <- in.out(bnd = as.matrix(as.data.frame(bnd2[[2]])), 
              x = as.matrix(dat[,c("x", "y")]))
dat2 <- dat[-which(hit),]
hit <- in.out(bnd = as.matrix(as.data.frame(bnd2[[2]])), 
               x = as.matrix(knots))
knots2 <- knots[-which(hit),]

plot(y ~ x, dat)
lapply(bnd2, lines)
points(dat2[,c("x", "y")], pch = 20, col = 3)

plot(y ~ x, dat2)
lapply(bnd2, lines)



Finally, I fit a few models of increasing complexity:

fit1 - single spatial soap term and temporal term (works)
fit2 - separate spatial soap terms for boundary (sf) and soap film (sw), and temporal term (works)
fit3 - additional spatiotemporal interaction term using ti(), but not a soap film (works)
fit4 - additional spatiotemporal interaction term using ti(), defined as soap film term (does not work)

# fit soap film gams -------------------------------------------------------

## fit1 - single spatial soap term and temporal term --------
fit1 <- gam(z ~ 
  s(x, y, bs = "so", xt = list(bnd = bnd2)) +
  s(time, k = nt),
  data =  dat2, method = "REML", knots = knots2, 
  family = gaussian(link = "log"))

plot(fit1, pages = 1)
summary(fit1)

## fit2 - separate spatial soap terms for boundary (sf) 
## and soap film (sw), and temporal term --------

fit2 <- gam(z ~ 
  s(x,y,bs="sf", xt=list(bnd=bnd2)) +
  s(x,y,bs="sw", xt=list(bnd=bnd2)) +
  s(time, k = nt),
  data =  dat2, method = "REML", knots = knots2, 
  family = gaussian(link = "log"))

plot(fit2, pages = 1)
summary(fit2)

AIC(fit1, fit2) # similar fit

## fit3 - additional spatiotemporal interaction term using ti(), 
## but not a soap film --------

fit3 <- gam(z ~ 
  s(x,y, bs="so", xt=list(bnd=bnd2))+
  ti(time, x, y, d = c(1,2), bs = c("ds", "ds"), k = c(nt,10)) +
  s(time, k = nt),
  data =  dat2, method = "REML", knots = knots2, 
  family = gaussian(link = "log"))

plot(fit3, pages = 1)
summary(fit3)

## fit 4 - attempt at spatiotemporal interaction soap film 
## term does not work  --------
fit4 <- gam(z ~ 
  s(x,y, bs="so", xt=list(bnd=bnd2)) +
  ti(x,y,time, bs=c("so", "ds"), d=c(2,1), 
      xt = list(list(bnd = bnd2), NULL)) +
  s(time, k = nt),
  data =  dat2, method = "REML", knots = knots2, 
  family = gaussian(link = "log"))

# Error in smooth.construct.tensor.smooth.spec(object, 
#  dk$data, dk$knots) : 
#   Sorry, tensor products of smooths with multiple penalties 
#   are not supported.

I'm a bit of a loss on how to proceed. fit3 seems to be explaining the data very well, but the spatiotemporal term does not contain a hole, and thus may be incorrect for my real data set where the boundary conditions are more important. Nevertheless, given the soap term in fit3, that model still will not provide predictions within the hole.

Another wrinkle
I have come across one example that seems to split the spatiotemporal interaction into "sw" and "sf" terms, but have not gotten this formulation to work for me when I have a hole in the soap film. This does however fit to the data without the hole (fit6), but the fit is quite a bit worse when compared to a similar model to fit3 (below, fit5) in terms of explained deviance and AIC:
fit5 <- gam(z ~ 
  s(x,y, bs="so", xt=list(bnd=bnd)) +
  ti(time, x, y, d = c(1,2), bs = c("ds", "ds"), k = c(nt,10)) +
  s(time, k = nt),
  data =  dat, method = "REML", knots = knots, 
  family = gaussian(link = "log"))

plot(fit5, pages = 1)
summary(fit5)

fit6 <- gam(z ~ 
  te(x,y, time, bs=c("sf","ds"), d=c(2,1), 
    xt=list(list(bnd=bnd), NULL)) +
  te(x,y, time, bs=c("sw","ds"), d=c(2,1),
    xt=list(list(bnd=bnd), NULL)) +
  s(time, k = nt),
  data =  dat, method = "REML", knots = knots, 
  family = gaussian(link = "log"))

plot(fit6, pages = 1)
summary(fit6)

AIC(fit5, fit6)
#            df       AIC
# fit5 148.6194 -5697.111
# fit6 103.6616 -2283.358

Hopefully someone has an idea for me. Fitting soap film smoothers seems to be q bit niche, and I have had difficulty finding material on the subject.

This isn't in-depth enough for an answer, but I believe the issue you are seeing is due to the fact that multiple penalties are needed when you have nested boundaries in the so family of basis classes. If you run some of the examples in smooth.construct.so.smooth.spec and use smoothCon() to inspect individual smooth terms, you will see that the non-nested ones set up with sf or sw result in an object with only a single penalty matrix in the element S. But the nested example (the last example) gives two penalty matrices. This obviously isn't allowed in tensor products :(

Please do not include rm(list = ls()) in code posted here. Somebody just copying your code could get angry!
